# Can I use a generic return type without having to downcast?

Tags: generics, design-patterns, swift4

I have 2 different types of credential objects in my code.

What I'm trying to do is use a generic function to construct and return the correct object based on Object.TYPE

So essentially I want to change the return type and the construction based on whatever condition.

My code seems to be working but in my implementation I need to use a `forced downcast`.

I also had to create a `"dummy protocol`" for my 2 different credentials which also seems "wrong"

This makes me suspicious that Im going about it the wrong way.

How can I do this without downcasting?

```
public protocol C {    
}
```

**// Generic Creation method**

```
public enum Credentials {
    case CredentialsIA(apiKey: String, apiSecret: String)
    case CredentialsO(username: String, secret: String, ipsName: String)
    func crendential<T:C>( type: T.Type) -> T {
        switch self {
        case .CredentialsIA(let apiKey, let apiSecret):
            return IACredentials(kAPIKey: apiKey, kAPISecret: apiSecret) as! T
        case .CredentialsO(let username, let secret, let ipsName):
              return OCredential(kUsername: username, kAPIKey: secret, kIPSName: ipsName) as! T
        }
    }
}
```

**Credential Types**

```
public struct IACredentials: C {
    public let kAPIKey: String
    public let kAPISecret: String
    public init(kAPIKey: String, kAPISecret: String) {
        self.kAPIKey = kAPIKey
        self.kAPISecret = kAPISecret
    }
}
public struct OCredential: C {
    public let kUsername: String
    public let kAPIKey: String
    public let kIPSName: String
    public init(kUsername: String, kAPIKey: String, kIPSName: String ) {
        self.kUsername = kUsername
        self.kAPIKey = kAPIKey
        self.kIPSName = kIPSName
    }
}
```

**Instantiation**

```
let credentialsA: Credentials = Credentials.CredentialsIA(apiKey: kAPIKey, apiSecret: kAPISecret)

let credentialsB : Credentials = Credentials.MIPCredentialsOriient(username: "sds", secret: "sdsd", ipsName: "sssd")
```

**Usage after init**

```
 let credential:IACredentials = credentialsA.crendential(type: IACredentials.self)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use your specific class without downcasting. But there is another issue.

Your code seems like a template method implementation with smething missing. Your dummy `interface`.

I think, you shuold ask this question yourself: What makes `CredentialsIA` and `OCredential` same, What is their common point. And use this in your interface. If you can do it, you can use your interface to perform tasks without need to know what their exact type are. Otherwise, you need downcasting.

Exaple:

```
protocol C{
    func myCommonPointFunc() -> Something
}

class CredentialsIA: C{
    func myCommonPointFunc() -> Something{
        //implementation
    }
}

class OCredential: C{
    func myCommonPointFunc() -> Something{
        //implementation
    } 
}
```

Usage:

```
let credentialsA: Credentials = Credentials.CredentialsIA(apiKey: kAPIKey, apiSecret: kAPISecret)
var result = creadentailsA.credential().myCommonPoinFunc()
```

Also, this method prevents you to pass your class type to your `enum`'s `credential()` method. You can even use `factory classes` that implement a `factory interface` instead of an `enum`

Maybe this [link](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/template_method) can be helpful.